# Where is the unit square send by the polynomial $z^2 + 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem** Where is the unit square send by the polynomial $z^2 + 2$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I analyzed the border of the unit square which the points are $it, 1+it, t, t+i$ where $t \in [0,1]$ then we have $f(z)=z^2+2$ so,

$$f(it)=-t^2+2, f(1+it)=3-t^2+i(2t), f(t)=t^2+2, f(t+i)=t^2-1+i(2t)$$

where the imgage of it is $1 \leq f(it) \leq 2$, the second $2 \leq Re(f(1+it)) \leq 3$ and $0 \leq Im(f(1+it)) \leq 2$, third $2 \leq f(t) \leq 3$ and fourth $-1 \leq Re(f(t+i)) \leq 0$ and $0 \leq Im(f(t+i)) \leq 2$, but what happen in the interval $[0,1]$ in the image of $z^2+2$. Could you help me to describe the right region please?

Comment: See the first image in https://cmgreen.io/2015/12/24/the-ahlfors-iteration.html

Comment: Define the unit square.

Comment: @zhw, the formulas given by the OP imply that it's $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: @lhf  Yes, you're right.